# How to intentionally fail $model->save() for testing?

Tags: yii2, codeception

I have this code in my controller class:

```
public function actionRevoke($id) {
    $model = Token::findById($id);
    $model->revoked_at = new Expression('NOW()');
    if ($model->save()) {
        Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('success', 'Revoked token');
    } else {
        Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('danger', 'Failed to revoke token');
    }
    return $this->render('revoke',['model' => $this]);
}
```

Now, running CodeCeption with code coverage, it tells me, the part with `setFlash('danger',...)` is not covered by tests.

How can I intentionally fail the `$model->save()` to trigger the `setFlash('danger,...)` instruction?

I would really like it, if I do not need to add extra code to my Controller exclusively for testing. So in particular, I don't want something like `if ($model->save() && !defined('TEST_FAIL_SAVE')) {` if it can be avoided.

Comment: apply a validation rule  to  your model .. and don't respect in input values .. model->save() performa validation for the model and return false  if fails

Comment: I'm not sure, I follow. I should add a validation rule to my model, but ignore it during normal operation. During testing, I enable the rule and the saving fails due to the failed validation. I guess, I will use scenarios for that?

Comment: you could also use schenario .. but you can just build a test with validation rule respcted  and one not ..

Comment: But if I create an impossible validation rule (like "token must be no longer than 0 chars"), I would have to deactivate validation during normal operations, right?

Comment: you can also send a model  ..  not based on form input .. you can call the action passing a post build by code  ..for test

Comment: add handler `beforeSave()` in your model. & return false if testing for false. ;

Comment: @Kalu that would be my last resort, because I do not want code solely for testing in the actual application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was (as suggested by @scaisEdge) to use validation rules. I added a rule, which enforces the length of `$model->token` to exactly 36. My application generates only tokens exactly 36 chars long. In my test, I use update the row in the database to show `abcd` as token, which is clearly less than 36 chars.
As this change is made on database level, it bypasses the validation of Yii and is committed to the database.

During the test, it changes the value of `$model->revoked_at` and attempts to save it, but fails the validation because `$model->token` is too short.

Here is the relevant part in the test function, the code of the controller was not changed:

```
public function revokeToken(FunctionalTester $I){
    // login and navigation to relevant page
    Yii::$app->db->createCommand()->update('tokens',['token' => 'abcd'],['id' => 201 ])->execute();
    $I->click('a.btn.btn-danger');             /* click the 'revoke' button, this triggers actionRevoke($id) */
    $I->seeFlash('Failed to revoke token');    /* expect a flash message */
}
```